# Translated Nodes Redirect To Homepage

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8.6.9 and have four languages setup:

- English *(Default)*
- Spanish
- German
- French

When I create a node of any content type and publish it as each one of these languages, everything seems fine when logged in. When I log out and view these pages they're fine again, but only for the default language. If I try to view a translated version of a node I just get redirected to the site's root back on the default translation.

I'm using URL detection which works when logged in fine.

There are no custom permissions setup and everything is properly published.

I can see that the redirect is a `308 Permanent Redirect` from looking at the dev tools.

I've tried rebuilding permissions, clearing the cache etc with no success, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you’re just using URL detection?

Comment: @Clive Yes as well as the default 'Selected language' option you cannot disable. I tested disabling 'URL' detection and changing the 'Selected language' to French which worked when logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was arising from a change I'd made to the KernelRequestSubscriber where I was redirecting users that hit the homepage that wasn't on the actual root of the site (to stop the homepage from being accessible from multiple routes - duh).